# GetX controller not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a User folder, inside the folder:

1. bindings
2. controllers
3. views

In my bindings file, I have wrote

```
Get.lazyPut<UserController>(
      () => UserController(),
    );
```

In my view file, I try to call controller.count
And there is an error saying that UserController not found.
If I add this code to my view file then it works. I don't understand why my binding not working.

```
final UserController controller = Get.put(UserController());
```

Edit:
I found the answer to this question.
I did not use GetBuilder in my view file. That's why it keeps saying my controller not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make the connection between your view and your binding. You can do that either in the `GetMaterialApp` like this:

```
getPages: [
  GetPage(
    name: '/',
    page: () => HomeView(),
    binding: HomeBinding(),
  ),
  GetPage(
    name: '/details',
    page: () => DetailsView(),
    binding: DetailsBinding(),
  ),
];
```

or when you navigate to a page:

```
Get.to(Home(), binding: HomeBinding());
Get.to(DetailsView(), binding: DetailsBinding())
```

More here: https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/dependency-management/binding/

Comment: I use get_cli so both pages you mentioned are automatically created. I found my problem... did not use getbuilder lmao. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No worries, I am glad you found out the issue.